# The size of objects in xcode get changed automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using Xcode 8.0 with objective c and auto resizing without any constraints.
Whenever I open my Xcode project all the coordinates of all my objects get changed by 1 or 2 points in a very random manner. For example, i have a button with coordinates (100,50,120,120) when I open the project again it would get changed to may be (101,48,126,121). And because of this, my whole application gets weird and the whole application has a dislocated layout.
Please advice what to do?

UPDATE:
[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko5UF.png) of the storyboard as requested. Check the second scene. It was supposed to have a width of the screen but it got reduced automatically

SOLVED
It was a bug in Xcode 8.0, I updated to Xcode 8.1 and it is working fine now.

Comment: Please show code/storyboard etc

Comment: are you using a custom font?

Comment: I am using one custom font - OpenSans ... I'll just update the post with the screenshot of the storyboard.